# How to write external PHP code to a div in another PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So hear me out, I want to do a live search of employees in a database and have them show up in a page of my website. I want their employee data to appear on the screen along with some radio buttons to edit their information. Here are the components of the task I have so far:

Javascript: index.php 
`

```
//Search bar functionality
    $(document).ready(function() {
        load_data();
        function load_data(query) {  
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetchUsers.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{query:query},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        function ajaxCall2(data){
          $.ajax({
            url:"showEmployees.php",
            method:"POST",
            data2:{data:data}
          })


        }
                }
            });
        }

        $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
            var search = $(this).val();
            if(search != '') {
                load_data(search);
            } else {
                load_data();
            }
        });
    }); 

</script>`
```

So the above code is doing the live search, the results are being stored in data. That works.

fetch.php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_information;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
  if(isset($_POST["query"]))
  {

    $users= $db->prepare("
      SELECT * FROM login_information 
      WHERE user_name LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ");
    $users->execute();
    $users = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($users);
    }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
```

This is the PHP code that runs in the ajax call for the live search. NOW for each element in my array,$users, I want this code to be run and displayed in index.php:

```
                    echo "
                            <div class=employeeContainter>
                                <div class=employeeInformation>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>User Name:  " . $row['user_name'] . "</li>
                                        <li>User ID:    " . $row['user_id'] . "</li>
                                        <li>User Email: " . $row['user_email'] . "</li>
                                        <form action='editEmployee.php' method='POST'>
                                            <label for='NotEmployed'>Not Employee</label>
                                            <input type='radio' id='NotEmployed' name='Employee'";          
                                                if($row['isEmployee']==0) echo "checked='checked'/>";
                                                else echo "/>";
                                  echo "<br><label for='YesEmployed'>Employee</label>
                                            <input type='radio' id='YesEmployed' name='Employee'"; 
                                                if($row['isEmployee']==1) echo "checked='checked'/>";
                                                else echo "/>";
                                  echo "<br><input type='submit' name=updateButton value='Update User'/>
                                        </form>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         ";
```

https://gyazo.com/16899aa7a6426310e42ee9090eef3158

This is a picture of how I want things to work. I know how each part works individually but I cannot figure out how to get everything to work together. I know this is a long post but any help at all would be appreciated

**EDIT**:

So I've been recreating the PHP code in javascript here is where I'm at

```
    function generateEmployeeData(employees){

      employees.forEach(function(d){


        var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var informationDiv = document.createElement('div')

        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        var br2 = document.createElement('br');

        //form
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute("action","editEmployee.php");
        form.setAttribute("method","POST");

        //labels
        var yesLabel = document.createElement('label');
        var noLabel = document.createElement('label');
        yesLabel.setAttribute("for","YesEmployed");
        noLabel.setAttribute("for","NotEmployed");

        //Radio buttons
        //buttons need to have the same name so only one is selected 
        var yesButton = document.createElement('input');
        var noButton = document.createElement('input');
        yesButton.setAttribute("type","radio");
        yesButton.setAttribute("name","Employee");
        yesButton.setAttribute("id","YesEmployed");

        noButton.setAttribute("type","radio");
        noButton.setAttribute("name","Employee");
        noButton.setAttribute("id","NotEmployed");

        if(d.isEmployee == 1){
          yesButton.setAttribute("checked","checked");
        }

        else{
          noButton.setAttribute("checked","checked");
        }

        //submit button
        var submit = document.createElement('input');
        submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
        submit.setAttribute("name","updateButton");
        submit.setAttribute("name","updateButton");
        submit.setAttribute("value","Update User");


        containerDiv.setAttribute("id","employeeContainer");
//        containerDiv.setAttribute("class","employeeContainer");
        informationDiv.setAttribute("id","employeeInformation");
//        informationDiv.setAttribute("class","employeeInformation");

        document.getElementById('results').appendChild(containerDiv)
        document.getElementById('employeeContainer').appendChild(informationDiv)
        document.getElementById('employeeInformation').appendChild(ul)




        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = "User Name: "

        var li2 = document.createElement('li');
        li2.innerHTML = "User ID: ";

        var li3 = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = "User Email: "

                //generating the header for item card
                var employeeHeaderDiv = document.createElement("div");
                employeeHeaderDiv.setAttribute("class", "employeeHeader");
                //generating the name div for the header 
                var employeeNameDiv = document.createElement("div");
                employeeNameDiv.setAttribute("class", "employeeName");
                var employeeNameTextNode = document.createTextNode(d.user_name);
        var employeeEmail = document.createTextNode(d.user_email);
                //prevent issues with display if the name for an item is too long
//              if(employeeNameTextNode.length > 15){
//                  employeeNameTextNode = document.createTextNode(d.employeeName.slice(0,13) + "...");
//              }
//              employeeNameDiv.appendChild(employeeNameTextNode);

        ul.appendChild(li);
        ul.appendChild(li2);
        ul.appendChild(li3);
        li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML+ d.user_name;
        li2.innerHTML = li2.innerHTML+ d.user_id;
        li3.innerHTML = li3.innerHTML+ d.user_email;

        ul.appendChild(form);

        form.appendChild(noLabel);
        noLabel.innerHTML = "Not Employee"; 
        form.appendChild(noButton);
        form.appendChild(br);

        form.appendChild(yesLabel);
        yesLabel.innerHTML = "Employee";
        form.appendChild(yesButton);
        form.appendChild(br2)

        form.appendChild(submit);

      });


    }
```

This is what it looks like so far: https://gyazo.com/c5cb9cd6cae92ccba502a9d0efe82076

So I've made some progress, this function is being called in the success function of my ajax call so essentially on every keyup in the search bar. However, I have a few problems.

1. I can select both radio buttons but I need to be able to only select one at a time. *Solved by giving each radio button the same name*
2. If I continue typing new results are just appended below what I already have instead of updating what I have.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to update that user is employee or non-employee only isn't it?

Comment: you don't set that inside a form..just do it as another ajax function...just set that submit button to call ajax funciton with that user id as parameter...

Comment: You need to put all those `html` content in JS. Make some JS function which excepts parameter employee `data` (json). Call this function in JS loop for each employee. And ofcourse then dump(append) it in HTML DOM.

Comment: @Jana it's a live search, that submit button is for a drop down menu that I am replacing and won't be used

Comment: @Jigar I tried to do that at one point but I'm getting stuck. Could you perhaps show me an example?

Comment: @H-man7 Okay. Show us what you tried. We will fix that. Also when is `ajaxCall2()` called, it is only defined in the `success` of `fetchUsers.php` ajax.

Comment: @Jigar Ok I will edit my question with my progress

Comment: Side-remark: take advantage of jQuery to [build dynamic element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I was able to solve my own problem but since someone may run into a similar problem as me one day I'll post my solution. The code in the edit is all set but as for updating the entries I just made another function called removeEmployeeData and placed it into my ajax function before I call generateEmployeeData:

```
  function removeEmployeeData(){
    $("div#employeeContainer").remove();
  }
```

So my ajax function now looks like:

```
$.ajax({
          url:"fetchUsers.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{query:query},
          dataType: 'json',
          success:function(data) {

          removeEmployeeData();  
          generateEmployeeData(data);
          console.log(data);


                    }
                });
```

Combine this with the above code and you now have a live search feature like this: https://gyazo.com/5efa11e50845afe8964c5dae6a9597e2